# why an object from a template class cant return a value?

Tags: c++

```
template <class type , int maxSize> class queue {

private: 

    type q[maxSize]; 
    int sloc, rloc; 

public: 

    queue(); //default constructor
    void put_new_element(type element); 
    type get_element(); 
};


template <class type , int maxSize> queue<type, maxSize>::queue()
{

    sloc = rloc = 0; 

}



template <class type , int maxSize> 
void queue<type,maxSize>::put_new_element(type element)
{

    if (sloc == maxSize) 
    {
        cout << "Q is full";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ++sloc;
        q[sloc] = element;
    }

}


template <class type , int maxSize>
type queue<type, maxSize>::get_element()
{

    if (sloc == rloc) 
    {
        cout << "Q underflow" << endl ;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //q[1] - q[100]
        ++rloc;
        ***return q[rloc];*** 
    }
}

int main()
{

    queue<int, 2> iq;

    iq.put_new_element(1);
    iq.put_new_element(3);
    //iq.put_new_element(5); //error q is full  

    cout << "int Q:" << endl;
    cout << iq.get_element() << endl; //1
    cout << iq.get_element() << endl; //3
    //cout << iq.get_element() << endl; //error q underflow

    queue<double, 3> dp;
    dp.put_new_element(1.3);
    dp.put_new_element(3.2);
    dp.put_new_element(5.3);    
    //dp->put_new_element(5); //error q is full


    cout << "double Q:" << endl;
    cout << dp.get_element() << endl; //1.1
    cout << dp.get_element() << endl; //3.2
    cout << dp.get_element() << endl; //5.3
    //cout << dp.get_element() << endl; //error q underflow

}
```

> The first part of main()(about int queue) runs properly when my
>   programm goes to second part , all set elements for double q are ok .
>   but when it calls the return function it throws(read access violation
>   this was 0x23B9246) .can someone explain to me why this happening ?
>   (this is my first months in c++ learning, lovely language :D <3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your bug is in your put function. You add one to the location before you write to that array location. It looks like you skip index 0 and overwrite the end of the array.

Because of oddities of array layouts and alignments you sometimes get away with this. Then the size changes and you do not get away with it.

Comment: that was it bro  . q[sloc]; sloc++;  and return q[rloc++] and works perfect , thanks alot :D

Answer (score 1):

Putting `if (sloc == maxSize)` check prior to increment `++sloc;`makes it useless so may still get out of bounds access. You have this problem all over the place. You should at least put assert prior to accessing array to catch error of this type more quickly.